# Show that F2 has an infinite index free subgroup of rank 2

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, geometric-group-theory

I am trying to show that F2 (the free group on 2 elements) has an infinite index, free subgroup of rank 2.

As it has to be a free subgroup of rank 2 I'm guessing I need to find 2 elements in F2 that generate a free subgroup together (satisfying no relations between them), and then also add in the constraint that the group they generate has infinite index in F2.

However, I'm really struggling to get my head around what it means for a group to have 'infinite index' and how, even if I found such a pair of elements somehow, how I could prove that they had infinite index in F2.

Also, this question occurs before material about topological methods such as covering spaces, so I would like to answer this without such tools, so I guess purely algebraically.

Any hints, suggestions or indeed solutions would be much appreciated.

Comment: See the example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen–Schreier_theorem): it shows you how to construct a subgroup of $F_2$ that is free on three elements. The subgroup generated by any two of those three elements is free of rank 2 and of infinite index.

Comment: Seriously? This question was marked as duplicate of a question which was answered using algebraic topology, when OP asked for a solution which doesn't use it?

Comment: @Rose141 Anyway, try the subgroup $H$ which is generated by the elements $a, b^3$.

Comment: Thanks @Mark - Indeed I've already seen the post that Rob Arthan has linked too, but as you noticed I was interested in algebraic methods instead. With the elements you suggested may I ask: is this group of infinite index in F2 as all even powers of b are not contained in $<a,b^3>$? And thus F2 quotient $<a,b^3>$ contains all elements of the form $b^{2k}$$<a,b^3>$ which are all distinct and of which there are infinitely many?

Comment: @Rose141 A general non trivial element of $F_2$ can be uniquely written in the form $s_1^{n_1}s_2^{n_2}...s_r^{n_r}$ where $n_1,...,n_r$ are non zero integers, and $s_1,...,s_r\in\{a,b\}$ with $s_i=a\iff s_{i+1}=b$. So $H$ is the subgroup of such words where all the powers of $b$ are divisible by $3$. So note that for integers $m>n>0$ the cosets $(ab)^mH$ and $(ab)^nH$ are distinct, as the element $(ab)^{m-n}$ definitely contains a power $b$ which is not divisible by $3$, and so can't belong to $H$. So these are infinitely many cosets.

Comment: Ah I understand, thank you! Just to check though, by exactly the same logic would the subgroups generated by $a^3, b^3$ or say $a, b^2$ also work?

Comment: @Rose141 Yes. Actually, $\langle a,b^k\rangle$ would work for any $k>1$.

Comment: Here's another suggestion. Let $x$ be obtained by mashing the $a$ and $b$ keys on your keyboard randomly a bunch of times: for example $x = abbbabababab$. Do the same for $y$ and $z$, for example $y=aababbabbababababa$, $z = baabbbababa$. With very high probability, $\{x,y,z\}$ freely generate a rank 3 subgroup of $F_2 = \langle a,b \rangle$, and this subgroup is of infinite index.